# Web-Hosting from laptop to internet

Tags: web, web-hosting

I want to host my website from my laptop to the internet. I have done everything I could. I have done the following:

1. used xampp with port 80
2. made my system ip static
3. port forwarding in the router (port 80 to my laptop)
4. turned on the remote management on router
5. set apache and mysql private as well as public in firewall

but when I search with my public ip it's not showing my website.
Please help me with the solution. I am in need of this.

Comment: You want it in Local > this is what you mean ? or to actually host it online so everybody can see it ?

Comment: I want it online

Comment: You might get some ideas from "The External Client" section https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: You have to host it in order to put it online. Look at ngrok documentation if it's just to look at it for a moment online. If you want to host it for a while. You need a domain name and host it on service like heroku or bluehost